# Get users who took ride for 3 or more consecutive dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have below table, it shows `user_id` and `ride_date`.

```
+---------+------------+
| user_id | ride_date  |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | 2019-11-01 |
|       1 | 2019-11-03 |
|       1 | 2019-11-05 |
|       2 | 2019-11-03 |
|       2 | 2019-11-04 |
|       2 | 2019-11-05 |
|       2 | 2019-11-06 |
|       3 | 2019-11-03 |
|       3 | 2019-11-04 |
|       3 | 2019-11-05 |
|       3 | 2019-11-06 |
|       4 | 2019-11-05 |
|       4 | 2019-11-07 |
|       4 | 2019-11-08 |
|       4 | 2019-11-09 |
|       5 | 2019-11-11 |
|       5 | 2019-11-13 |
+---------+------------+
```

I want `user_id` who took rides for 3 or more consecutive days along with days on which they took consecutive rides

The desired result is as below

```
+---------+-----------------------+
| user_id | consecutive_ride_date |
+---------+-----------------------+
|       2 | 2019-11-03            |
|       2 | 2019-11-04            |
|       2 | 2019-11-05            |
|       2 | 2019-11-06            |
|       3 | 2019-11-03            |
|       3 | 2019-11-04            |
|       3 | 2019-11-05            |
|       3 | 2019-11-06            |
|       4 | 2019-11-08            |
|       4 | 2019-11-09            |
|       4 | 2019-11-10            |
+---------+-----------------------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/02688/1)

Comment: Thank you for including the ddl, sample input, and sample output. The only thing missing here is your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to adress this gaps-and-island problem:

- first, assign a rank to each user ride with `row_number()`, and recover the previous `ride_date` (aliased `lag_ride_date`)
- then, compare the date of the previous ride to the current one in a conditional sum, that increases when the dates are successive ; by comparing this with the rank of the user ride, you get groups (aliased `grp`) that represent consecutive rides with a 1 day spacing
- do a window count how many records belong to each group (aliased `cnt`)
- filter on records whose window count is greater than 3

Query:

```
select user_id, ride_date
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        count(*) over(partition by user_id, grp) cnt
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            rn1 
                - sum(case when ride_date = dateadd(day, 1, lag_ride_date) then 1 else 0 end)
                over(partition by user_id order by ride_date) grp
        from (
            select 
                t.*,
                row_number() over(partition by user_id order by ride_date) rn1,
                lag(ride_date) over(partition by user_id order by ride_date) lag_ride_date
            from Table1 t
        ) t
    ) t
) t
where cnt >= 3
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/02688/41)**

Answer (score 2):

With `LAG()` and `LEAD()` window functions:

```
with cte as (
  select *,
    datediff(
      day,
      lag([ride_date]) over (partition by [user_id] order by [ride_date]),
      [ride_date]
    ) prev1,
    datediff(
      day,
      lag([ride_date], 2) over (partition by [user_id] order by [ride_date]),
      [ride_date]
    ) prev2,
    datediff(
      day,
      [ride_date],
      lead([ride_date]) over (partition by [user_id] order by [ride_date])
    ) next1,
    datediff(
      day,
      [ride_date],
      lead([ride_date], 2) over (partition by [user_id] order by [ride_date])
    ) next2
  from Table1  
)
select [user_id], [ride_date]
from cte
where 
  (prev1 = 1 and prev2 = 2) or
  (prev1 = 1 and next1 = 1) or
  (next1 = 1 and next2 = 2)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e054990620e4033ed309a71df436b259).
Results:

```
> user_id | ride_date          
> ------: | :---------
>       2 | 03/11/2019
>       2 | 04/11/2019
>       2 | 05/11/2019
>       2 | 06/11/2019
>       3 | 03/11/2019
>       3 | 04/11/2019
>       3 | 05/11/2019
>       3 | 06/11/2019
>       4 | 07/11/2019
>       4 | 08/11/2019
>       4 | 09/11/2019
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical gaps and island problems.

We can solve it as follows

```
with data
  as ( 
      select user_id
             ,ride_date
             ,dateadd(day
                      ,-row_number() over(partition by user_id order by ride_date asc)
                      ,ride_date) as grp_field
        from Table1
       )
     ,consecutive_days
     as(
  select user_id
         ,ride_date
         ,count(*) over(partition by user_id,grp_field) as cnt
    from data
       )
 select *
 from consecutive_days
 where cnt>=3
 order by user_id,ride_date
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7bb851d9a12966b54afb4d8b144f3d46

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to apply gaps-and-islands methodologies to this problem.  The problem is much simpler to solve.

You can return the users and first date just by using `LEAD()`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             LEAD(ride_date, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY ride_date) as ride_date_2
      FROM table1 t1
     ) t1
WHERE ride_date_2 = DATEADD(day, 2, ride_date);
```

If you want the actual dates, you can unpivot the results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_id, v.ride_date
FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             LEAD(ride_date, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY ride_date) as ride_date_2
      FROM table1 t1
     ) t1 CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (t1.ride_date),
             (DATEADD(day, 1, t1.ride_date)),
             (DATEADD(day, 2, t1.ride_date))
     ) v(ride_date)
WHERE t1.ride_date_2 = DATEADD(day, 2, t1.ride_date)
ORDER BY t1.user_id, v.ride_date;
```